GPU Thread Management
I'm currently working on a ray tracing algorithm for a non-image rendering application, utilizing both CUDA and OpenCL for GPU acceleration. My algorithm processes more than 1 million rays, and I'm curious about how these rays are partitioned among threads for efficient computation.
In CUDA, I'm launching the kernel function as follows:
cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&minGridSize, &blockSize, GPU_trace_rays, 0, raySize);
gridSize = (raySize + blockSize - 1) / blockSize;
GPU_trace_rays<<<gridSize, blockSize>>>(...);


And calculating the thread ID as:
int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
Similarly, in OpenCL, I'm using:
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(chunk_ray_size), cl::NullRange);


And calculating the thread ID as:
int tid = get_global_id(0);
Despite not explicitly assigning multiple rays to a thread, I've observed correct results with operations like:
int arrayC[threadID] = arrayA[threadID] + arrayB[threadID];
Could someone help me understand how CUDA and OpenCL handle the partitioning of rays among threads? I'm particularly interested in how these frameworks efficiently distribute the workload across the available threads, especially when dealing with large numbers of rays since I sometimes I have more rays than available threads.

Section 1.3 of the CUDA Prgramming Guide: each block of threads can be scheduled on any of the available multiprocessors within a GPU, in any order, concurrently or sequentially, so that a compiled CUDA program can execute on any number of multiprocessors […], and only the runtime system needs to know the physical multiprocessor count.

See also: What is the behavior of thread block scheduling to specific SM's after CUDA kernel launch?

If you are launching more threads (or rather more blocks) than can be resident on the available SMs, they will be scheduled sequentially in so-called waves. If there is significant setup each thread has to do once independent of the number of rays, it could be advantageous to run a single wave and do the sequential loop over rays explicitly inside the kernel. also, if there is a partial wave and few full ones your performance could suffer from the tail effect.

If you want to try running a single wave, take a look at the example code for grid synchronization. It shows how to use the CUDA runtime API to find out how many threads/blocks you can run in a single wave.

I really don’t understand what you are asking: “ Could someone help me understand how CUDA and OpenCL handle the partitioning of rays among threads?” CUDA and OpenCL don’t do that. You as the programmer have to manage it, meaning that your kernel code does it. Are you really asking us to explain your own code (which we can’t see) to you?

Consider this operation on GPU kernel; int arrayC[threadID] = arrayA[threadID] +arrayB[threadId] and lets say each array has 10 million elements. I am simply executing this kernel and my results are all correct. What happens if the number of threads on my GPU is less than 10 million? I don't do any thread management. I dont say each thread needs work with 2 indexes if we want to compute all. I run the program and results are correct for each element.

On an abstract, simplified level, think of the GPU having some sort of work queue. Individual thread blocks are work items. When you launch a kernel, all blocks for that kernel launch are placed in the queue and then are scheduled to be processed by the GPU. When you launch fewer than what the GPU can handle, it goes partially idle. When you launch more thread blocks, some will only start running once the first wave of blocks has finished. There is no guarantee that all thread blocks run at the same time or in any particular order.

From performance point of view, it makes sense to create as much workitems as there are hardware threads:
int num_blocks_per_sm = 0;    
cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(
    &num_blocks_per_sm, GPU_trace_rays, threads_per_block, shmem));
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&device_prop, dev);
grid_size = device_prop.multiProcessorCount * num_blocks_per_sm;
....
GPU_trace_rays<<<grid_size, threads_per_block, shmem>>>(ray_size,...);

In the kernel, loop over rays:
__device__ size_t get_global_id()
{
    return blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
}

__device__ size_t get_global_size()
{
    return gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
}

__global__ void GPU_trace_rays(size_t ray_size, ...)
{
    for (size_t ray = get_global_id(); ray < ray_size; ray += get_global_size()) {
         ....
    }
}

It is safe to set threads_per_block to 32.
(Edit: suggested by Homer512) The optimal threads_per_block is this:
threads_per_block = device_prop.maxThreadsPerMultiProcessor / device_prop.maxBlocksPerMultiProcessor;

Note that cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor won't work in OpenCL, although you can use this heuristic:
compute_units = device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>();
work_items = compute_units * 512;
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(GPU_trace_rays, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(work_items));


"It is safe to set threads_per_block to 32." Safe sure but horrible for performance. Many SM architectures allow only 16 blocks per SM. With 1 warp each that makes for only 16 warps while up to 48 would be possible with bigger block sizes. See this table. You can determine the ideal blocks size for maximizing occupancy using Nsight Compute, but for a sane start I would use at least 128.

paleonix: threads_per_block is threads per block, not blocks per SM. Never set less than the warp size (32).

paleonix is correct. You limit the occupancy if you define only 32 threads per block because your kernel runs into the limit of  resident blocks per SM. You need at least 64 threads. For CUDA version 8.6 and 8.7, you need 96. So 128 is a reasonable value. Just divide the Maximum number of resident threads per SM by the Maximum number of resident blocks per SM in the table that he linked

Makes sense, especially for diverged threads. Added this suggestion. Thanks.
